# Can we have some option of convert a comment to a question

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions

Sometimes we find that a comment in a question or answer is itself a question, which can be taken up separately. I was just thinking if we could have a button to convert a comment to a new question. It would be a handy approach. THe SE staff can decide about whether the control is to be given to moderator or all users o to user with specific reputation.

Comment: It seems I did a crime asking for something. I just put forward a thought. And if it is not to be followed then no upvotes or approx 5 downvotes can make me and other people understand that its not worthy. Targeting a question by more and more downvotes is making me feel that i did a crime putting forward a thought. It will all the more discourage people to not put forward any thought as then one will loose all his reputation. I request people to please think and then downvote. There are already enough downvotes that can make people understand that its not worthy so no need of more downvotes.

Comment: Please understand that [voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), particularly since you tagged this as [tag:feature-request]. You, as a user, didn't do anything wrong, so no need to worry.

Answer (score 11):

I think this would be a bad idea.

Comments are only written by many as their quick thoughts about a question or answer, and are therefore not composed with the quality we seek for questions in mind.  Consequently, once converted you would expect that they would need some improvement (as well as a title and tags).  However, I suspect some users would just think "great button, easiest question I'll ever write, job done".

Personally, if I have written or read something and think it would make a good question, I just hit the Ask Question button and copy/paste the good bits from the comment in as I compose my question.

Comment: I understand your point but not accepting the answer as I have already flagged the question and asked the mods to delete the question. I am not sure if I accept your answer then it can be deleted or not.

Comment: @Aby mods can just nuke the question and its answers if they want, but I doubt they will do it just because the request is heavily downvoted, unless there are more serious problems...

Answer (score 8):

Comments are so brief (<600 characters) that it's so simple to just rewrite (or even copy-paste) the comment text and turn it into a question if necessary, **and also add in the additional detail** that would be required for it to be a decent question.

A quick save of time would not necessarily equate to an increase in quality of question. Quite the reverse, I think.